# Delimitar áreas especificas de una imagen y asociarla a un evento click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

Estoy trabando con modelos de arquitectura con frames png y jpg, y necesito delimitar areas de cada imagen para asociarlas a clases css y a eventos click, he intentado hacer esto marcando el area con un color y asociar dicho color a un evento pero he tenido complicaciones con esto debido a los matices de colores, estuve viendo que con la etiqueta `<map>` podria delimitar areas dentro de una imagen y asociarla a eventos

[image: Maqueta de edificio]

Comment: Mi opinión sería que hagas un svg con tu imagen. En dicho svg pones de fondo tu imagen y mapeas zonas. Así podrás acceder a dichas zonas a través del don de dicha imagen svg, puesto que puedes ponerles atributos, id...

Answer (score 2):

En este ejemplo utilizo la la etiqueta `<map>`. Si pasas con el ratón por encima del polígono rosa podrás ver que este es un link.

```html
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/SOFTest.jpg" usemap="#name" width="504" height="582" >
<map name="name" >
    <area alt="alt" href="http://example.com" coords="88,241,164,213,168,221,203,207,215,227,196,237,204,256,211,253,222,274,151,302,80,276,90,243" shape="poly" >
</map>
```

Otra posibilidad, todavia mejor, tal como dijo @Jakala sería utiliar SVG:
En este case he dibujado un polígono encima de la zona rosa.

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 504 582">
    <image id="IMG" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/SOFTest.jpg" width="504" height="582"></image>
  
  <a xlink:href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">
  <polygon points="86,244 165,214 166,222 201,209 213,228 201,235 222,270 152,303 80,276" fill="rgba(255,0,0,.3)" />
  </a>
</svg>
```